# How do I append a random string to a filename before an optional extension?

Tags: c#, string, algorithm

**Goal:** Given a file name and directory, if there is a file with the same name in the directory, append the file name with a "random" string of digits and save it in the directory. Don't assume that the file name has an extension.

**Example:**

```
somepic.jpg --> somepic19232139195.jpg

somepic --> somepic19232139195.jpg
```

**Attempt at solution:**

```
 string suffix = (DateTime.Now.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond).ToString();
 int thisIndex = newFilePath.LastIndexOf('.');
 newFilePath = newFilePath.Insert(thisIndex != -1 ? thisIndex : newFilePath.Length, suffix);
```

**Problem:** Isn't working for files without extensions, and I can't figure out why. `somepic` (no extension) becomes `somepic` with current solution.

**Additional question:**

Does C# have an integral type I should be using instead of `int` in the above code? Does it have an integral type guaranteed to hold the maximum size of a string, the equivalent of `size_t` in C++?

Comment: Look at [Path::GetFileNameWithoutExtension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of trying to parse it.

Comment: You know, if you have (as in your example) a file named "somepic.jpg" and "somepic" your code will probably try to rename those files to the exact same name, either crashing or overwriting. That is, you can process a lot of files until your suffix changes.

Comment: [Your code seems to work just fine](http://ideone.com/hj4iK0).

Answer (score 4):

I think that this problem can be addressed in a better way.

Try with this

```
string extensionFile = newFilePath.GetExtension();
newFilePath = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(newFilePath);
newFilePath += suffix;
newFilePath += string.IsNullOrEmpty(extensionFile) ? String.Empty : extensionFile;
```

**Updated:**
Workaraound to Siada comment, if you have files only with extension like ".gitignore"

```
string extensionFile = newFilePath.GetExtension();
string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(newFilePath);

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
{
    newFilePath += fileName + suffix;
    newFilePath += string.IsNullOrEmpty(extensionFile) ? String.Empty : extensionFile) 
}
else 
{
    newFilePath = extensionFile.Insert(1, suffix);
}
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that if your file is for example a '.gitignore', this ends up breaking the file because it'll just take the .gitignore as the extension and add your suffix to the start rather than the end and thus end up with '19232139195.gitignore'

Answer (score 0):

**Caveat:** If you have (as in your example) a file named "somepic.jpg" **and** "somepic" your code will probably try to rename those files to the exact same name, either crashing or overwriting. That is, you can process a lot of files until your suffix changes.

Otherwise, something like this should work, assuming all files are ".jpg":

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    using System;
    using System.Globalization;
    using System.IO;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RenameJpegFiles(@"c:\tmp");
        }

        private static void RenameJpegFiles(string path)
        {
            foreach (var filename in Directory.GetFiles(path))
            {
                string suffix = (DateTime.Now.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                var fileNameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename);

                var newFilename = string.Format("{0}{1}.jpg", fileNameWithoutExtension, suffix);
                var newFullFilename = Path.Combine(path, newFilename);

                File.Move(filename, newFullFilename);

                Console.WriteLine("Renaming: {0} -> {1}", filename, newFullFilename);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
Renaming: c:\tmp\somepic.jpg -> c:\tmp\somepic63569994418865.jpg
Renaming: c:\tmp\some_other_pic -> c:\tmp\some_other_pic63569994418865.jpg
Press any key to continue . . .
```